# Can't open my channel on youtube from application

Tags: ios, youtube, safari, youtube-api, openurl

I use this code for open my channel:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/user/myChannel"]];
```

If I paste this string to Safary, everything is great. If Safary was opened everything is great Too. And I can see this:

[image]

BUT if Safary wasn't opened before. I can see only proposition for download Youtube application from the app store:

[image]

I tested it on iOS 7,8. There are the same behavior. But on iOS 9 betta 4 it looks different behavior(Back button in top left corner) and absolutely no problems:

[image]

I think it is not my problem. But maybe some of you had/have the same problem with youtube or some another service. In the nearest time I am going to send mail to youtube support, but may be there is simple solution and i don't know about it =(

PS

Any way. Tank for your attention =)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7440&thanks=7440&ts=1437651882

Comment: Have you noticed any other apps that prompt a download from the app store? It may be an app indexing issue.